# Javascript adding number to table cell id using for-loop accumulator

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, cell

I have a for-loop here which appends a table row and its element every time it is looped. I am trying to append a td id as well for future use. But to prevent the ids from being repeated, I have to make sure every id is unique. Is there anyway I can add number after my current td ID, visitorChanges using the loop accumulator?

```
for (var i = 0; i < datas.date.length; i++) {
                eachDay = dayShortToLong[datas.date[i]];
                totalVisitor = datas.valueIn[i];
                totalVisitorLastWeek = datas.lastValueIn[i];

                    $("#tableMonthlyTrend").find('tbody')
                    .append($('<tr>')
                        .append($('<td class="tableContentDay">')
                        .text(eachDay)                                
                        )
                        .append($('<td class="tableContent">')
                            .text(totalVisitor)
                        )    
                        .append($('<td class="tableContent">')
                            .text(totalVisitorLastWeek)
                        )
                        .append($('<td id="visitorChanges" class="tableContent">')
                            .text('No Changes')
                        )
                    );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `string` and `number` so its value can be set dynamic

`.append($('<td id="visitorChanges" class="tableContent">')`

change to

`.append($('<td id="visitorChanges' + i + '" class="tableContent">')`

Or you can set the id of the `td` after it creates:

`$('<td class="tableContent">').attr("id", "visitorChanges" + i).text('No Changes')`